# Preventing Mongoid 4.0.0 model field coercion of id => _id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I'm using Mongoid 4.0.0 with Rails 4.  My models map tables in another application, and I have no control over the field names.

One of the models has a field named `id`, which is getting coerced into Mongo's `_id` field.  For example, when I insert a document with an `id` value of `"something"` I get

```
{_id:"something", id:null}
```

instead of

```
{_id:ObjectId("<hexstring>"),id:"something"}
```

Is there any way to avoid this coercion, make Mongoid not conflate the two fields, and leave my `id` field alone?

As I said, renaming the `id` field is *not* an option.

Thanks!

[edited]
This is definitely *not* a MongoDB issue.  It must be in Moped or (my guess) Mongoid.

I've tried changing the `params` key from `:id` to `:_rid` but this is still happening.  I'm going to check out aliases, but from my first pass I don't think they're going to help -- they appear to go the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be hardcoded into `Moingoid` and a pervasive assumption throughout.  It's annoying enough, though, that I might come up with a patch to allow users to override the key field on a *per*-model basis.

Oh well.